# Getting the filename associated with a sample in the "Downloadable Information" area in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm working on a customization of the "Samples" block on Products. Basically what I need to know is how to get the file name from a sample.

So, I can use the following code in my view to get an array of samples:

```
<?php $_samples = $this->getSamples() ?>
```

... and I can iterate over those samples well enough. What I'm trying to figure out, is, how can I get the name of the file associated with that sample? I basically want to do a customization to the view where, if the sample file is an MP3, I display an embedded player. For all other file types, the default behavior (a link is shown, which when clicked, opens a new window and displays the sample) is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you concatenate $samplePath and $sampleFile together, you get the full path the the sample file, on disk. i.e.:  `$samplePath . $sampleFile` gets you `/path/to/samples/folder/sub-folder/path/to/file.mp3`

In this example, it's actually not necessary to get the $samplePath, since you can just test whether or not $sampleFile ends with ".mp3", as shown below, but I wanted to demonstrate how to get to the full path anyhow.

```
<?php
if ($this->hasSamples()):
    $_samples = $this->getSamples();

    foreach ($_samples as $_sample):
        $samplePath = $_sample->getBasePath(); // returns "/path/to/samples/folder"
        $sampleFile = $_sample->getSampleFile(); // returns "/sub-folder/path/to/file.mp3"

        // Figure out if the filename ends with ".mp3"
        $_is_mp3 = (bool)(".mp3" == substr($sampleFile, -4));
        if ($_is_mp3):
            //show the mp3 player
        else:
            //show a link to the file
        endif;

    endforeach;

endif;
?>
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot tomorrow and let you know. Looks like the getSampleUrl() and/or getSamplePath() will get me what I need. Thanks!

Comment: This got me headed in a good direction, but the best I could do with the methods mentioned above, as well as other ones that I found in the API, was get the base directory for the samples, e.g. /path/to/app/samples, rather than /path/to/samples/1/sample.mp3. I may just have to add this functionality. Luckily (I think), Magento is open source.

Comment: Does the [getURL()](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Downloadable/Mage_Downloadable_Model_Sample.html#getUrl) function not return a full path to the file? If so, you can either trim the string up to the dot before the file extension to determine the file type, or use [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006632/php-how-can-i-check-if-a-file-is-mp3-or-image-file/2006664#2006664) if the full file path returned by getURL() points to a download ID rather than the file itself.

Comment: Nope, the getURL() function returns the URL (e.g. http://example.com/samples/01/), which (a) doesn't include the filename, and (b) just delegates to your browser to handle the view/playback of the sample appropriately. For example, the URL, if the sample is a PDF, will launch whatever your default PDF viewer is. In the case of .MP3s, for me the URL was launching my default media player, locally on my machine.

Comment: So I modified your answer to include the working code. I don't know if you have to approve it before it shows up, but you definitely got me going in the right direction, and I found the code that does it thanks to your help.

Comment: @normalocity - PHP's [`substr()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) accepts a negative start position, so you can eliminate the `$start` and `$length` variables with the same effect

Comment: Sweet. Even better!